# How can I search for fonts which support specific characters?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

How can I search for fonts which support specific characters?

For example, how can I find a font which has the character [U+1000](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1000/browsertest.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The website you are using actually searches for fonts which support specific characters.

**Steps:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### O_O